# Force android to display email type keyboard in HTML5 page based web application

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

I have designed an **HTML5** page which consists of a input box of type email. This HTML5 page will be displayed in **Android application** in a **webview**.

```
<input type="email" autofocus id="emailid"/>
```

The problem I'm facing is that Android doesn't show the **email type keyboard** which has the "`@`" and "`.com`" symbol by default.

How to force **Android** to display **email type keyboard** using any of these?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Using anything like phonegap, titanium or a like? Think potentional helpers would like to know.

Comment: Nope, it'll be an independent app. Basically an android app as i already mentioned before, which will be running a HTML5 page within it. The bottleneck i'm facing right now is to always have an email friendly keyboard across all devices.

Comment: what version of android are you using to test?

Comment: It should support all common Android versions. ICS detects the email type input but other versions launch the default soft keyboard.

Comment: @pansp In general its depends on browser, so I cannot controll which keyboard to show for each input type

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky : Do u mean if i run the same html code on some browser other than default browser, it will open the correct keyboard type across all Android versions?

Comment: @pansp it depends on browser :) but chance is very big that it will open the correct keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, HTML5 is not fully supported on devices running 2.2 or below.
These are not supported:

```
input type=search
input type=tel
input type=url
input type=email
input type=datetime
input type=date
input type=month
input type=week
input type=time
input type=datetime-local
input type=range
input type=color
input type=checkbox
input type=image
textarea
select
datalist
keygen
output
progress
field validation
form validation
APIs
Spellcheck attribute
Session history
Geolocation
Device Orientation
FileReader API
Local Storage
Access the camera
Full Screen
```

And the confirmation: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/768.cfm

Try running your app on ICS or JB and it should work.

Comment: Yes, it works fine on ICS. But ICS is yet to catch grounds. I need support atleast for Android 2.3 and 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to detect version of Android OS on server and to the next:

1) if OS = ICS or above => use native html 5

2) if OS < ICS => show custom html keyboard

Also for OS < ICS in your app disable soft keyboard.

Comment: If I had to use custom keyboard, I would have used across all OS. A custom html keyboard will need lot of work to make it compatible for all size of devices and OS types. All i need is Android displays the email friendly keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Keyboards are completely pluggable in Android - and therefore somewhat unpredictable.  Device manufacturers almost always ship a custom keyboard (which can introduce problems, For example: I've seen some HTC keyboards not handle IME_ACTIONS).  Also, users are free to download and use many different keyboards from the Play Store.  Certain keyboards may not have an email style - maybe because the developers didn't think of it, or maybe because it's not appropriate.  For instance: Something like [Graffiti keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.access_company.graffiti&hl=en) might legitimately ignore the email style completely?

I believe the best you can do is handle the cases that are supported.  If >=ICS supports the input type="email" and older versions don't, at least over time your user base should shift towards a higher percentage of users getting the behavior you want.

I don't know what your app looks like, but another option if you really want the @ sign and .com keys to be visible would be to use a hybrid approach where you add only those keys to your html and allow users to tap those or use the normal pluggable Android keyboard for everything else (or @ signs and .com's also - if their keyboards include it)